# How to interpret this regular expression /[\W_]/g

Tags: javascript, regex

My code is:

```
var result2 = result.replace(/[\W_]/g,"").replace(",","").replace(".","");
```

The code works i get what i need done, but I don't understand how the regular expression `/[\W_]/g` works, and I can't find any documentation that i understand.

Comment: `/[\W_]/g` will match non-word characters and underscores. The `/g` matches globally. [See this cheat-sheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/javascript).

Comment: I strongly recommend that you go to the http://regexr.com/. There, click at "Reference". It's a very good place to learn about regular expressions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/` ... `/g`  It's a global regex.  So it'll  operate on multiple matches in the string.
`[` ... `]` This creates a [character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets).  Basically it'll match any single character within the listed set of characters.
`\W_`  This matches the [inverse of "word characters"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-word) and underscores.  Any non-word character.

Then you have a few one off replacements for comma and period.  Honestly, if that's the complete code, `/[\W_,.]/g`, omitting the two other replaces, would work just as well.

Answer (score 3):

1. \W means "any non word character"
2. [\W_] means "any non word character or a _
3. /[\W_]/g find globally any non word character or _

`replace` find all occurences of a regexp, and replace it with another string.

So your expression replace any non word character, or _, or . to an empty string (ie, remove it)

it can be simplified to :

```
result.replace(/[\W_,\,]/g,"")
```

Answer (score 2):

`[` and `]` are the start and end of a character set.
`\W` means "non-word", as opposed to `\w` which will match a word.
`_` is the "_" character.
`/` mark the beginning and end of a regular expression.
`g` means it's a global search.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

\W Matches any non-word character. Equivalent to [^A-Za-z0-9_].

For example, /\W/ or /[^A-Za-z0-9_]/ matches '%' in "50%."

the underscore (_) matches a literal underscore

The brackets define a character class meaning that the regexp will match if any non word or an underscore character is present

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's break it down. `replace(/[\W_]/g, "")` means replace every non-word character and underscore with an empty string.  So in the string $1.00, it would come out as 100 ($ and . are non-word characters).

Then `.replace(",","")` removes commas.

And `.replace(".","")` removes periods.